# Why is pop faster than shift?

Tags: javascript, performance

Douglas Crockford, in *JavaScript: The Good Parts*, states that "shift is usually much slower than pop". jsPerf [confirms this](http://jsperf.com/popvsshift). Does anyone know why this is the case? From an unsophisticated point of view, they seem to be doing pretty much the same thing.

Comment: In IE 6 it isn't. :-)

Comment: for searchers, this is the cleanest jsperf I've found: http://jsperf.com/shift-vs-pop-and-reverse-plus-pop/1

Comment: @zamnuts: That test does not actually use the result of `pop()` or `shift()`, so modern browsers optimize it to a no-op. Here is a modified version that shows `pop()` is indeed faster than `shift()`: http://jsperf.com/shift-vs-pop-and-reverse-plus-pop/7

Comment: Several years later, you should check the jsperf in the above comment.  In Chrome 61, shift was actually FASTER, though by a teeny bit.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To remove the returned item without re-addressing the array and invalidating all references to it, `shift()` requires moving the entire array around; `pop()` can simply subtract 1 from its length.

Comment: Addendum: as far as I know, no JavaScript implementation currently does what Perl does, keeping a start offset so that `shift` can simply increment that. It *could*, though, which would eliminate that slowdown.

Comment: using a start index means extra work to get each index because you have to go *startIndex + index* to get the one you want. I suspect that if shift operations were really popular, a startIndex or similar would be implemented but since direct property access is much more popular, better to optimise for that.

Comment: @RobG: I wasn't so much asking why they didn't, as explaining why the quote said "usually".

Comment: Realistically this all depends on two things, the number of read and writes going on, and then the size of the array.... smaller arrays would be better off renumbering, while constant read and writes in an array that doesn't change size often would be better with renumbering as well, just some thoughts.

Answer (score 33):

`shift()` has to re-index the whole array while `pop()` doesn't.

`pop()` simply removes the last element in the array. Therefore, the elements do not move; simply the `.length` has to be updated.

`shift()` removes the first element in the array. This requires a re-indexing of all elements in the array, so that `[1]` becomes `[0]` and so on.

Answer (score 18):

I was doing some tests on this with node (which uses chrome v8) and noticed that for arrays up to around 120k elements the performance of shift is pretty close to pop.  Once you get bigger than 120K it seems to slow down dramatically.

```
var sum;
var tests = [125000,130000];

console.log(JSON.stringify(process.versions));

tests.forEach(function(count) {
    console.log('Testing arrays of size ' + count);
    var s1 = Date.now();
    var sArray = new Array(count);
    var pArray = new Array(count);
    for (var i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
      var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
      sArray[i] = num;
      pArray[i] = num;
    }
    console.log(' -> ' + (Date.now() - s1) + 'ms: built arrays with ' + count + ' random elements');

    s1 = Date.now();
    sum = 0;
    while (pArray.length) {
      sum += pArray.pop();
    }
    console.log(' -> ' + (Date.now() - s1) + 'ms: sum with pop() ' + count + ' elements, sum = ' + sum);

    s1 = Date.now();
    sum = 0;
    while (sArray.length) {
      sum += sArray.shift();
    }
    console.log(' -> ' + (Date.now() - s1) + 'ms: sum with shift() ' + count + ' elements, sum = ' + sum);
});
```

Output:

```
{"http_parser":"1.0","node":"0.10.22","v8":"3.14.5.9","ares":"1.9.0-DEV","uv":"0.10.19","zlib":"1.2.3","modules":"11","openssl":"1.0.1e"} 
Testing arrays of size 125000
-> 14ms: built arrays with 125000 random elements
-> 2ms: sum with pop() 125000 elements, sum = 436673
-> 6ms: sum with shift() 125000 elements, sum = 436673 
Testing arrays of size 130000
-> 50ms: built arrays with 130000 random elements
-> 1ms: sum with pop() 130000 elements, sum = 455971
-> 54372ms: sum with shift() 130000 elements, sum = 455971
```

Comment: I'm not seeing that in chrome.  Even for small arrays, shift seems much slower than pop: http://jsperf.com/push-pop-vs-unshift-shift/3

Comment: I noticed that Chromium 76 starts to have [bad shift performance](http://www.lonniebest.com/BadShiftPerformance/) around 15,044 elements and above, while Firefox 69 is much faster.

Answer (score 3):

Because shift() reindex array so the shift method is very slow on large array.

```js
var array = [];
for(var i = 0;i< 1000000;i++){
    array.push(i)
}
var start = new Date().getTime()
for(var i = 0; i< 100000; i++){
 array.shift();
}
var duration = new Date().getTime() - start;// duration is so large, greater than 3 minutes
```

But the duration is just 8ms when using linked-queue

```js
var LQueue = require('linked-queue')
var queue = new LQueue()
for(var i = 0;i< 1000000;i++){
    queue.enqueue(i);
}
console.log("Queue length:"+ queue.length);
var start = new Date().getTime()
queue.dequeueAll(function(data){
})
var end  = new Date().getTime();
console.log("Time:" + (end - start));// 8 ms
console.log("Queue length:"+ queue.length);
```

Comment: The array experiment has a bug. You shift only 100 000 elements, after pushing 1 000 000 elements. I would edit, but the change is too small. Good that you are relating this to queues, but I would like to see an example with alternating operations. Say 1000 pushs followed by 1000 shifts, 10 000 times (or more). I imagine the offset optimizations of array will sooner or later cost too much memory and require reallocations. The linked list does not have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

The difference can be negligible—Unoptimized executors may run `shift` much slower than `pop`, but optimized ones won't.

You can optimize like this:

```
let WrapArray = _=>{
  //Ensure no other ref to `_`.

  let numlike = _=>isNaN(_)?false:true
  let num = _=>Number(_)
  {
    let shift_q = 0
    return new Proxy(_, {
      get(first_t, k){
        switch(k){
          case 'shift': return (z={})=>(z.r=first_t[0 + shift_q], delete first_t[0 + shift_q++], z.r)
          break; case 'length': return first_t.length - shift_q
          break; default: return first_t[numlike(k)?num(k) +/*todo overflowguard*/shift_q:k]
        }
      },
      set(first_t, k, v){
        switch(k){
          case 'length': first_t.length = v + shift_q
          break; default: first_t[numlike(k)?num(k) +/*todo overflowguard*/shift_q:k] = v
        }
      }, 
      has(first_t, k){
        return (numlike(k)?num(k) +/*todo overflowguard*/shift_q:k) in first_t
      },
      deleteProperty(first_t, k){
        delete first_t[numlike(k)?num(k) +/*todo overflowguard*/shift_q:k];return 543
      },
      apply(first_t, t, s){
        first_t.call(t, s)
      },
      construct(first_t, s, t){
        new first_t(...s)
      },
    })
  }
}
(_=WrapArray(['a','b','c'])).shift()
console.log(_.length/*2*/, _[0]/*b*/, _[1]/*c*/, _[2]/*undefined*/)
```

Comment: I do not understand this, but it is impressive that you thought of this.

Answer (score 1):

If you shift, you have copy all the elements in the array backwards.  To pop, you only need to decrement the length of the array.  Technically, an implementation could get around this, but you would need to store an extra `shift' variable that tells you where the real start of the array is.  However, this type of operation has not proven to be very useful in practice and so most implementations save space by only storing a start of array pointer and a length value.

Comment: The overhead couldn't possibly be that large if one stored memStart, arrStart, memLength and arrLength. Then elements would be accessed as arrStart+index if 0 <= index < arrLength else undefined. You would not have to calculate arrStart at every access. And reallocation/GC could follow similar logic as that on the other end of the array.