# Remove first Item of the array (like popping from stack)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have list of items created via `ng-repeat`. I also have Delete button.
Clicking delete button removes last item of the array one by one. **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QDuklfthp2g7MMAoWxIx?p=preview)**

But I want to remove items one by one starting from the first item. How can I do that? I used this for removing list Items:

```
  $scope.index = 1;
  $scope.remove = function(item) { 
    var index = $scope.cards.indexOf(item);
    $scope.cards.splice(index, 1);     
  }
```

Is there any way I can remove from the top?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003815/how-to-remove-first-element-of-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp

Comment: [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/2oY4akhOThr64f19Yzim?p=preview)

Answer (score 503, accepted):

The easiest way is using `shift()`. If you have an array, the `shift` function shifts everything to the left.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]; 
var theRemovedElement = arr.shift(); // theRemovedElement == 1
console.log(arr); // [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: If you need to iterate through the whole array and remove one element at a time until the array is empty, I recommend reversing the array first and then using `pop()` instead of `shift()` as `pop()` is faster `shift()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501160/why-is-pop-faster-than-shift

Comment: upvoted! lets say I want to keep an array with 1000 elements at any point in time and I keep adding new data every second or so, how efficient is shift in such a scenario

Comment: @AlexanderJank But that doesn't work if the array is `[1,2,3,a,b,c]`

Answer (score 132):

Just use `arr.slice(startingIndex, endingIndex)`.

If you do not specify the `endingIndex`, it returns all the items starting from the index provided.

In your case `arr=arr.slice(1)`.

Comment: I prefer this `slice()` because `slice()` isn't invasive and doesn't change the value itself unlike `shift()` or `splice()`.

Cf.

<!-- language: lang-js -->

var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = a.shift()

a
//(2) [2, 3]

b
//1

Comment: both methods have different use cases.

Comment: Another advantage is chaining: [1, 2, 3].slice(1).doSomethingWithTwoAndThree()

Comment: Perfect. .shift() did not work for map(), slice did. :D

Answer (score 64):

```
const a = [1, 2, 3]; // -> [2, 3]

// Mutable solutions: update array 'a', 'c' will contain the removed item
const c = a.shift(); // prefered mutable way
const [c] = a.splice(0, 1);

// Immutable solutions: create new array 'b' and leave array 'a' untouched
const b = a.slice(1); // prefered immutable way
const b = a.filter((_, i) => i > 0);
const [c, ...b] = a; // c: the removed item
```

Answer (score 11):

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DxFPGrdJ2np83tAQqQGN?p=preview)

```
$scope.remove = function(item) { 
    $scope.cards.splice(0, 1);     
  }
```

Made changes to .. now it will remove from the top

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out this. if starting point is 0 then it starts from top

Answer (score 5):

There is a function called `shift()`.
It will remove the first element of your array.

There is some good [documentation and examples](http://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/javascript-array.html).