# Queue with Two Stacks

Tags: javascript, data-structures, stack, queue

I implemented a queue with two stacks like so:

```
class QueueTwoStacks {
  constructor() {
    this.stack1 = []
    this.stack2 = []
  }
  enqueue(item) {
    this.stack1.push(item)
    const lastItem = this.stack1.pop()
    this.stack2.push(lastItem)
    const lastItem2 = this.stack2.pop()
    this.stack1.push(lastItem2)
  }

  dequeue() {
    if(this.stack1.length === 0) throw Error
    return this.stack1.shift();
  }
}
```

The course I'm following gave this as an answer:

```
class QueueTwoStacks {
  constructor() {
    this.inStack = [];
    this.outStack = [];
  }

  enqueue(item) {
    this.inStack.push(item);
  }

  dequeue() {
    if (this.outStack.length === 0) {

      // Move items from inStack to outStack, reversing order
      while (this.inStack.length > 0) {
        const newestInStackItem = this.inStack.pop();
        this.outStack.push(newestInStackItem);
      }

      // If outStack is still empty, raise an error
      if (this.outStack.length === 0) {
        throw new Error("Can't dequeue from empty queue!");
      }
    }
    return this.outStack.pop();
  }
}
```

Is one better than the other, and if so, why? I feel like my solution is better because you don't have to loop, but maybe you're not supposed to do all the operation in the enqueue method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your implementation has O(n) time complexity for `dequeue` EVERY time, because you're calling `shift`. On the other hand, `pop` is an O(1) operation. For more details, you can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501160/why-is-pop-faster-than-shift).

Notice that in your implementation, you can pretty much get rid of `stack2` altogether and it'll still work (of course, with the same drawback that you'll have O(n) `dequeue`):

```
class QueueTwoStacks {
  constructor() {
    this.stack1 = []
    // this.stack2 = []
  }
  enqueue(item) {
    this.stack1.push(item)
    // const lastItem = this.stack1.pop()
    // this.stack2.push(lastItem)
    // const lastItem2 = this.stack2.pop()
    // this.stack1.push(lastItem2)
  }

  dequeue() {
    if(this.stack1.length === 0) throw Error
    return this.stack1.shift();
  }
}
```

The second implementation, however, only occasionally moves elements to the `outStack` (i.e. only when it is empty) and uses `pop` for its `dequeue` operation. So, while worst case is still O(n), in the average case, `dequeue` in this implementation should be O(1), which is considerably better than O(n), especially if you're going to be calling it many times.