# What is the Array format of pg_copy_from()'s input?

Tags: php, postgresql, postgresql-11

I am attempting to load *many* CSV files of historical data to a PGSQL server with PHP. I noticed PHP provides a `pg_copy_from()` function for loading local data into a remote server, but the exact format of the input is vague.

The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-copy-from.php) says it expects an array of rows, each row being a delimited string of the values in that row. PHP's `file()` function returns an array in a format as described, but feeding it into pg_copy_from() returns an error of:

```
$rows = file('path/to/data.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // Same result without ignore_new_lines
pg_copy_from($db, 'dest_table', $rows, ',');

'PHP Warning:  pg_copy_from(): Copy command failed: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""col_2""'
```

I checked the array, `$rows`, and it's of a format like this:

```
[index]=>""foo",3,7,"bar",500,"z""
```

Where all string values and the string itself are in double quotes. I assume it's trying to load the entire string into the 1st column of my table, hence the error that col_2 is unable to load (cause there's nothing *to* load).

Are my assumptions about the array wrong or does the delimited string need a different format (if so, how)?

Thanks for any help/tips!

Comment: I have a different guess. I think your CSV file contains headers and you're trying to set `col_2` as a value for an integer column

Comment: Your guess is correct! (man I am fried). I just added 
`array_reverse($rows)`;
`array_pop($rows);`
And it works!

Comment: To remove element from the beginning of the array `array_shift` is used.

Comment: I'm just avoiding `shift`'s [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501160/why-is-pop-faster-than-shift) @Wolph are you OK if I accept mulder's repost of your comment as answer?

Comment: @optimum yes go ahead. I don't care about the points anyhow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments by @Wolph - just remove first element of your `$rows` array, because it contains headers. To remove first element of array `array_shift` can be used **without** reversing the array:

```
$rows = file('path/to/data.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
array_shift($rows);
pg_copy_from($db, 'dest_table', $rows, ',');
```